# Angular 2: Specify location of the test classes

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have **Angular 2** project which is generated in **Angular Cli** tool. 
When I create component via:

```
$ ng generate component my-component-bla
```

the test class "**my-component-bla.spec.ts**" is generated as well and placed in the same directory.

**I wonder how can as set location for test classes to be automatically generated in separate directory.**

*(please note that I wrote that sample for component, but same apply for services, pipes, etc..)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but there is currently no feature like this for Angular CLI (see the complete reference for the generate command [here](https://cli.angular.io/reference.pdf)).

I guess the Angular team has decided that they think unit tests should go right in with the other source files. If you insist of having a root level test folder it seems that you must move the test files manually or write your own shell script that calls "ng g" and then moves the test file for you.